# Is SELECT transaction an expensive operation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I used transaction roll back to check how an inserted value looks in a table. But when I used `SELECT` it consumed a lot of CPU.

Is this because of the `SELECT` I am using? Should one not use `SELECT` inside a transaction? If this is the case, is there any other alternative other than using a temp table?

**UPDATE:**

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION
  INSERT INTO CompanyVal (country) VALUES ('USA')
  select * from CompanyVal
  END TRANSACTION
 ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the SELECT statement you wrote and the table you're querying? Was it a SELECT *, and how many columns are on the table/how many rows?

Comment: I have added a update this is what i am trying to do

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I have added it just SQL , sql-server